# angular-module-federation routing from micro frontend to shell

Tags: shell, routes, micro-frontend, angular-module-federation

I have angular microfrontnd application using angular-module-federation. It includes one main shell application and three microfronteds wrapped with web components. Microfrontends are using module-federation-tools's connectRouting function to connect shell routing with microfronteds routing. It is working well.

But... I have a case, where in microfronted application wrapped as web component is a link which provides to shell (like home button). Routing inside web component (microfronted) works pefectly fine.

Is there a possibility to trigger shell routing from microfronted wrapped with web component?